# php-fpm changed user can't create pid and sock files

Tags: apache2, nginx, php-fpm

I want to execute php-fpm with a different user in my Ubuntu workstation, so I changed the `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d` file according to some tutorials I found:

```
user = myuser
group = myuser
```

But when I try to restart php-fpm service, it crashes because my new user doesn't have permissions to create the pid and sock files under `/var/run` what totally makes sense since `/var/run` has root only permissions. But `www-data` was able to write under that folder and it didn't have any specials permissions as well, so I guess I must be missing some steps.

Do you know how to change the user of php-fpm and be sure it will be able to create the pid and sock files?

Obs: If I need to change the init script, I must say I'm not sure how to do it and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`php5-fpm` should actually be starting as root and dropping its privileges once it's set up and running. This is fairly common amongst webservers. This should allow it to write to a root-owned space and chown its own files.

I believe that is exactly how my installation works.
The question then becomes: why isn't yours?

Have you altered the Upstart script that ships with it to `chuid`? That would break it. Here's my `/etc/init/php5-fpm.conf` for comparison:

```
# php5-fpm - The PHP FastCGI Process Manager

description "The PHP FastCGI Process Manager"
author "Ondřej Surý <ondrej@debian.org>"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [016]

# you can uncomment this with recent upstart
# reload signal USR2

pre-start exec /usr/lib/php5/php5-fpm-checkconf

respawn
exec /usr/sbin/php5-fpm --nodaemonize --fpm-config /etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf
```